# weird design pattern in apollo-server subscribe

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-server

using the sample from official doc

```js
const POST_ADDED = 'POST_ADDED';

const resolvers = {
  Subscription: {
    postAdded: {
      // Additional event labels can be passed to asyncIterator creation
      subscribe: () => pubsub.asyncIterator([POST_ADDED]),
    },
  },
  Query: {
    posts(root: any, args: any, context: any) {
      return postController.posts();
    },
  },
  Mutation: {
    addPost(root: any, args: any, context: any) {
      pubsub.publish(POST_ADDED, { postAdded: args });
      return postController.addPost(args);
    },
  },
};
```

first, the subscribe resolver makes total sense:

```
Subscription: {
    postAdded: {
      // Additional event labels can be passed to asyncIterator creation
      subscribe: () => pubsub.asyncIterator([POST_ADDED]),
    },
  },
```

the graphql `postAdded` Subscription is connected to `pubsub` system's `POST_ADDED` event, check.

the mutation makes sense too:

```
Mutation: {
    addPost(root: any, args: any, context: any) {
      pubsub.publish(POST_ADDED, xxx);
      return postController.addPost(args);
    },
  },
```

when adding a post, emit a `POST_ADDED` event to `pubsub` system, check

but the weird part is the payload of event. 
why is it in this shape? 
`pubsub.publish(POST_ADDED, { postAdded: args });`

it makes more sense if it is like this:
`pubsub.publish(POST_ADDED, args );`

why the args has to be inside of an object with a key name equal to the subscription resolver??

when emitting event, it shouldn't have any awareness of the receiver. What is the reason of design things in this way. (and it doesn't work without that weird key...)